# Android Market App Generic Localization

Tags: android, localization, google-play

On android market isn't present a generic language like "pt" or "it", but i find only "it-IT" or "pt-PT", "pt-BR".

If i set "en-US" like primary, "en-AU" or "en-GB" can easy fallback to default "en-US".

But what if i put "pt-PT" only, instead to set doubled translation like "pt-PT" and "pt-BR"?

Can the store fallback to primary existent language or it fallback to "en-US" as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language variations (locales) fall back to an available page in the same language. I.e. if you only have a page in "pt-PT", a request for "pt-BR" will still be in portuguese.